# Logger4j throws ExceptionInInitiaizerError

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to `Log4j`. I am experienced with Java though.

I have written a small example to run a `Log4j` app.

```
package com.log;



import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



public class Log4jExample {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jExample.class.getName());



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.debug("Hello, this is a debug message.");
        log.info("Hello, this is an info message.");
    }
}
```

And this is my `log4j.properties` file that I manually created in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/`  directory.

```
# Define the root logger with appender X
log = /Users/aditya/Desktop/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Set the appender named X to be a File appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for X appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I am on Mac OS X.

I am running the code as:

```
javac com/log/Log4jExample.java
java com.log.Log4jExample
```

But this is what I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:37)
    at com.log.Log4jExample.<clinit>(Log4jExample.java:13)
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: What logging JAR files do you have on the classpath?  Somehow you seem to have called something that is creating an `slf4j` class rather than a `log4j` class.  This should not happen if you are using the regular log4j JAR file.

Comment: i downloaded the log4j libraries and copy pasted them un my $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext directory.

Comment: Which ones.  Where did you get them from?  You will need to be **precise** ...

Comment: logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html from this link

Comment: Please list the JAR FILES that you added.

Comment: all of them present in the directory after extracting the zip file. there are more than 15 jar files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have added an inappropriate logging JAR files to your Java installation's `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/`.

- Don't add 3rd-party JAR files to the "ext" directory, because that affects *all* applications that you run using that Java installation.  (And there is a fair chance that some of those JARs won't be appropriate to all of your applications; e.g. version mismatches, etc.)
- Don't just add all of the logging JAR files in the ZIP files.  The instructions on the web page you downloaded from state that you only need 2 of them ... not all 15 JAR files.

---

The problem seems to be caused by a JAR file that is designed to adapt log4j for use with the sl4fj logging facade.  The class `org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext` should not have been loaded, yet alone instantiated, in an application that uses log4j without the facade ... as you claim you are doing.

Comment: what 2 jars you talking about?

Comment: Read the instructions.